# creating a checkbox in JASMINE angular testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dom, jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function that checks the values of checkboxes that are created with *ngFor in the HTML. To test it, I wanted to make a checkbox that would normally be created in the app. However, I get this error:[image: typeError]

My Test:

```
 it(`should add agencies to the providedInfo array if checked`, () => {
    const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.id = "numberGiven_test4";
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    (checkbox as HTMLInputElement)!.checked = true;
    
    component.pageSevenNextButton();
    expect(component.formValue.value.providedInfo).toEqual([
      {
        name: "test4",
        phone1: "",
        phone2: "",
        address: "",
        website: "",
        remarks: "PQRST",
        referrals: []
      }
    ]);
    expect(component.pageCounter).toBe(8);
  });
```

I've tried wrapping it in "addEventListener" or "window.onload", but I still get the same error.

```
     window.onload = function(){
      const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
      checkbox.id = "numberGiven_test4";
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";
      checkbox.checked = true;
     }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
      checkbox.id = "numberGiven_test4";
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";
      checkbox.checked = true;
    });
```

Is there a certain way of doing this that I'm missing? Can I not create elements in a test?

**EDIT:** adding the corresponding HTML and TS to kind of show what's going on

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let agency of selectedAgencies">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <b>{{agency.name}}</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox" id="numberGiven_{{agency.name}}" >
                                </div>
                                <label for="numberGiven_{{agency.name}}" class="form-control listSelectCheckbox">Number Given</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
pageSevenNextButton(){
    for(let each of this.selectedAgencies){
      let inputID = "numberGiven_" + each.name;
      const element = this.document.getElementById(inputID) as HTMLInputElement;
      if(element.checked){
        let tempArray = [];
        tempArray = this.formValue.value.providedInfo;
        tempArray.push(each);
        this.formValue.patchValue({
          providedInfo: tempArray
        });
      }
    }
    this.pageCounter = 8;
  }
```

The error seems to be coming from when it reaches the `if(element.checked){` line in the component.ts.
(Also, I know it was mentioned that using document was bad practice, but I didn't find a better method for referencing dynamically created inputs.)

Comment: You need to call `detectChanges` on the fixture, otherwise the changes caused by your method call won't be taken into account. Also, it's a solidly terrible idea to use `document` methods in Angular. Bad code smell.

Comment: I am already calling `fixture.detectChanges();` in my "beforeEach", but thank you for the tip on `document`. I'll look into that. I'm still learning.

Comment: You need to call it _after_ you call `pageSevenNextButton()`, otherwise whatever changes the method causes in the template will not be detected.

Comment: oh, ok, interesting. Unfortunately, that still doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Wait I hadn’t actually read the test: why on earth are you trying to add something to the DOM inside a test?

Comment: I added the HTML and TS. My thought was that since the input is normally created dynamically, I would have to force-create an input so that my function could read it.

Comment: Wow OK now I understand. I'm afraid you're not doing things in a very Angular way. I suggest you follow some courses/tutorials before you start worrying about unit tests, because what you've done in `pageSevenNextButton()` isn't Angular code. I mean no offence: I simply mean that you need to learn to write proper Angualr before thinking about writing unit tests.

Comment: hmm ok, I didn't know that. Thank you for your help